# nginx 301 redirects

Tags: nginx

have recently changed the url structure of my website and have added a few redirects in nginx.

Since we are focussing on SEO the urls have changed over the past week, but google has cached some of the old urls already. I have added a redirect for most of the pages but not sure if this is the right syntax

I need to redirect something like

website.com/city/restaurants/suburb/name-ID to website.com/city/suburb/name-ID and want to get rid of the /restaurants/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx has great rewrite module. Read [docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite). Something like that should work for you.

```
rewrite  ^/(.*)/.*/(.*)/(.*-.*)$  /$1/$2/$3;
```

You can put it in your `server` caluse.

Also, you can put it inside `location` or `if` clause (still, better no to use `if`).

Comment: Yes that helped was not very sure about the .* but with some changes to the .* such as [a-zA-Z-0-9]+ I was able to get it working. Thanks!